# People Search Picture profiles give same photo

Tags: search-results, ups

I have a problem every time I search for a user or any property referring to the user I always get the first picture of the person on top before the other it's only after a refresh it's only then when I see others any java script or anything firing before?

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot with an example of what you are experiencing. This almost sounds like a browser caching issue.

Comment: You see these are different people and I don't think it's any browser caching issue because it's not just me but every one and only after I refresh then it brings back the right pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running a custom display template or other JavaScript on the page? The ID of the container is used to create a unique value for the persona. In your case it appears that all of the containers have the same value so the Persona is set to the same person. This should not happen out of the box. If it is, then file a SR.

If you have customizations running, remove them and determine which is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes I have a custom display template. I will troubleshoot though. Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/add-presence-to-sharepoint-search-results/